# How to configure Nginx so that http://localhost/tut/ goes to a named container without revealing its port number, and not throw a 404 error

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I am learning Nginx. I have an example setup with `nginx:1.23.3-alpine` in one container and the `docker/getting-started` in another, running on port 4444.

I have a default index.html at `http://localhost` which displays my correct "landing page".

I can reach my getting started tutorial container at `http://localhost:4444` which resolves to `http://localhost:4444/tutorial/`.

Now, I want to understand how to configure it so that the tutorial is reached via `http://localhost/tut/` and have it resolve to at least `http://localhost:4444/tutorial/` but even better `http://localhost/tutorial/`. All this is in preparation for setting up my actual stack where I want to use specific public urls to access containers on various ports but without revealing their port numbers, eventually all on HTTPS. Hence this simple initial test.

So...

`docker compose up` - no errors.

`http://localhost` returns 200

`http://localhost:4444` returns 200 from `http://localhost:4444/tutorial/`

**The problem:**

`http://localhost/tut/` returns 404 because, according to the logs it is looking for `/usr/share/nginx/html/tutorial/index.html`

```
my-nginx  | 2023/03/11 03:14:16 [error] 31#31: *6
"/usr/share/nginx/html/tutorial/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), 
client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /tutorial/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", 
referrer: "http://localhost/tut/"
```

I have tried having different server blocks and all sorts of things suggested in other posts but this is the closest I have come to a not-quite-working solution!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine
EXPOSE 80 443

# Copy in your SSL certs
# For when I test it with HTTPS
COPY certs/* /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost/

# Copy in your nginx config
COPY config/localhost.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy in your landing page example
COPY static-html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My Docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  my-nginx:
    container_name: my-nginx

    build: ./nginx/.

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

    networks:
      - my-network

  my-test:
    container_name: my-test
    image: docker/getting-started

    ports:
      - "4444:80"

    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network
    driver: bridge
```

My nginx localhost.conf file:

```
events {}
http {

  server {
      listen       80;
      listen  [::]:80;

      location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index  index.html index.htm;
      }

      location /tut/ {
        proxy_pass http://my-test:80/;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be some kind of pattern matching RegEx? issue with Nginx. Not really a bug? Not sure.

The getting-started container is designed to redirect to `/tutorial` and display the page content. All good.

*However*... if the location is any partial match of /tutorial a 404 results.
So, for the second location block in my conf file above:

```
/xxx works
/yes works
/tat works

but these result in 404
/t
/tu
/tut

and so on
```

The log says:

```
[error] 39#39: *10 "/usr/share/nginx/html/orial/index.html" is not found 
(2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.160.2, server: localhost,
request: "GET /orial/ HTTP/1.0", host: "my-test", referrer: "http://localhost/tut/"
```

Notice the url path: "/usr/share/nginx/html/**orial**/index.html" and the "GET /**orial**/ HTTP/1.0"